# C language syntactical ambiguity : looping construct switch contains different switching construct other than 'case'

Tags: c, switch-statement

Had some trouble reading the following code snipped in git repo.
link to repo and problem:

https://github.com/paolo-sz/fatty/blob/master/src/winmain.c#L2649

```
 switch (confirm_multi_tab()) {
      when IDNO:
        if (!cfg.confirm_exit || confirm_tab_exit()) {
          child_terminate(term->child);
        }
        return;
      when IDCANCEL:
        return;
    }
```

Could someone explain why there is a 'when' in the switch statement and not 'case' . Appreciate the help.

Comment: I've downloaded all the repo and I found in a header src/std.h:143 this: `#define when break; case`

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez Can we vote to have the author of this code shot?

Comment: @EOF haha I think so :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `std.h` file at https://github.com/paolo-sz/fatty/blob/master/src/std.h line 143:

```
#define when break; case
```